# GCC 4.4 fails to link valid C++11 code, when options are -std=C++0x -O0

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, g++

This is an edited question based on first answers. Others pointed out to me that code I supposed to be invalid was perfectly fine in C++11. Nevertheless the behaviour of `gcc` differs depending on something that should not be related.

---

There is a file, containing

```
std::string logFilePath;
/*...*/
std::ofstream logfile(logFilePath, std::ofstream::trunc);
```

this line compiles and links in windows (`MSVC2010`) and under linux (`G++4.4`) with `-std=c++0x` setting. When I give `-O0` option, linkage breakes and gives an error:

```
 undefined reference to `std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ofstream(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::_Ios_Openmode)'
```

The question is *why* this happens exactly? It seems to be a bug in `gcc` but any further info would be great.

There is an old [thread](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/50395/) concerning same problem, which led me to `-Ox` being culprit, but there is no explanation, only solution hint.

---

Here's a minimal example:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main (int, char**)
{
    std::string name = "name";
    std::ofstream stream(name, std::ofstream::trunc);
    return 0;
}
```

and then:

```
$ /usr/bin/g++44 -std=c++0x main.cpp -Wall -O1
$ /usr/bin/g++44 -std=c++0x main.cpp -Wall -O0
    /tmp/ccBjIuWi.o: In function `main':
    main.cpp:(.text+0x80): undefined reference to `std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ofstream(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::_Ios_Openmode)'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

first line compiles fine and gives expected behaviour disregarding of optimization level set, except for `-O0`, i.e. any of `1`, `2`, `3`, `s` will do.

---

Here's some additional info regarding system:

```
$ /usr/bin/g++44 -v
    Using built-in specs.
    Target: x86_64-redhat-linux6E
    Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --disable-gnu-unique-object --with-as=/usr/libexec/binutils220/as --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --disable-libgcj --with-mpfr=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.4.7-20120601/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux6E/mpfr-install/ --with-ppl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.4.7-20120601/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux6E/ppl-install --with-cloog=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.4.7-20120601/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux6E/cloog-install --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i586 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux6E
    Thread model: posix
    gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1) (GCC)
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
    CentOS release 5.9 (Final)
```

Comment: gcc 4.4 is ancient, and its c++0x mode surely broken/incomplete on many levels.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, unfortunately, I'm not able to switch gcc version

Answer (score 2):

That is because the code is not invalid in C++11. [A constructor taking an `std::string` as first argument](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream) was added C++11. The flag `std=c++0x` tells g++ to compile in C++11 mode (or whatever sub-set of the future C++11 it supported in your version)

In C++03, you need to pass a `const char*`:

```
std::ofstream stream(name.c_str(), std::ofstream::trunc);
```

As for the dependence on optimization level, this is most likely either a problem with your installation, or a genuine bug in that particular version of g++. Unfortunately I am not in a position to reproduce it.

Comment: although your answer seems same as @Vlad's but you have at least pointed out that optimization-dependence seems to be bug. Seems to be it, I didn't know about `std::string`-taking constructor being added, now this does not seem so misterious.

Comment: @idji Implicit in my answer is that the problem did nor occur in newer versions of g++. But it would help if you added the exact version (the x in 4.4.x) and, if possible, the OS. I may be able to check on some RH gcc 4.4 box later on.

Comment: I have edited the question to (hopefully) answer your question about version and other stuff.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor with std::basic_string was added in the C++ Standard 2011. Before it this constructor was not present. Instead of it the constructor with parameter of type const char * was used.